# bootstrap class not applied when set programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I add a select tag to a div "dataColumnBuilder" programmatically when user chooses a table name from dropdown list I have

```
<select class="dataTableSelect form-control" onchange="addFields();" onfocus="this.selectedIndex=-1;">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="tableName">tableName</option>
</select>
```

through calling this js function:

```
function addFields($datasetNm){
    var myDiv=document.getElementsByClassName("dataColumnBuilder");
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.setAttribute('data-placeholder', 'Choose Columns');
    selectList.setAttribute('class', 'chosen-select');
    selectList.setAttribute('tabindex', '4');
    selectList.setAttribute('multiple','');
    myDiv[0].appendChild(selectList);
    for (var i = 0; i <dataCols.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = dataCols[i];
        option.text = dataCols[i];
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

and

`$(function() {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen();
});`

it successfully adds a select tag to the div:

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose Columns" class="chosen-select" tabindex="4" multiple="">
    <option value="pgm_id">pgm_id</option>
    <option value="title">title</option>
    <option value="description">description</option>
    <option value="status">status</option>
    <option value="approved_date">approved_date</option>
</select>
```

The problem is I can't see the class "chosen-select" which is bootstrap class applied on the select list added programmatically.

Whereas if I add it to the html file directly I will see the class applied so I don't know what I am missing.

You can check the problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/Natalie77/96eds8vz/
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include a [mcve] using the stack snippet feature, or a link to a jsfiddle.

Comment: Instead of using the setAttribute function try using className like this: selectList.className = 'chosen-select'; Let me know if this worked for you!

Comment: @StephanGenyk I tried it didn't work :/

Comment: Then you will have to do what @zzzzBov wrote. Please include something we can test in order to fix this problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Natalie77/96eds8vz/  Please check the fiddle I created I hope everything is clear @zzzzBov @ StephenGenyk

Comment: @NatalieBoudakian, you wrote "The problem is I can't see the class 'chosen-select' which is bootstrap class applied on the select list.", however I'm not able to reproduce the issue. The generated markup includes the class you specified. As such, I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic (#2)](/help/on-topic). Please re-read the [mcve] description and update your question such that it actually reproduces the problem you're having.

Comment: @zzzzBov the markup includes the class but it is not applied on the list that is my problem at the first place. I even created a jsfiddle for it that shows that there is the same list with same class that has a different display than the one that has the same attributes but created programmatically. The votedown was so not neccessary I did every possible thing to make the problem clear!

Comment: @NatalieBoudakian, it wasn't clear to me that your issue was that the JS functionality wasn't being applied asynchronously to the newly created DOM nodes. You had said the class wasn't applied, which I interpreted as the class wasn't added to the DOM node.

Answer (score 1):

You call `$.fn.chosen` on DOM ready, but never call it again on newly created `<select>` elements.

Call `$(selectList).chosen()` after adding the node to the DOM.

---

<sub>Also, avoid mixing inline-javascript and jQuery, otherwise what's the point of adding jQuery at all?</sub>